# How to check if cluster is failover or load balancer in powershell?

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, load-balancing, failover

I'm new working with clusters and I was searching for a way to identify the clusters through powershell. Is there a way to get the clusters and check the type (load balancer/ failover)?
I looked at some powershell modules: Failover Cluester and Network Load Balancing. However both of them are specific to the cluster type, I was wondering if there is a general one.

Comment: There's the *failover cluster* module you can work with.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But my question is, is there any command that gives me that information? Does the command get-cluster (from that module) gives me the information that that cluster is a failover cluster?